# Java streams filter() condition

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-stream

I'm trying to use java streams and filter option. I have an instance(allowedToTradeProcessEquity) that contains a list of 2 items of another instance(Segment). I'm trying to filter allowedToTradeProcessEquity based on the value in on of the items in the list. Now to choose which Segment to take out of the list I need to check another condition (Hence two filter conditions). I feel this is not the best way to write this cause filter is a boolean and findFirst is an optional condition. Also, needed an idea on the right way to extract the inner filter option into a method.

PS: in this case there will be a Segment that matches the condition, it's just a matter of filtering and getting that segment out.

```
allowedToTradeProcessEquity= allowedToTradeProcessEquity.stream().filter(userProcessEquity -> userProcessEquity.getSegments().stream().filter(segment -> segment.getSegmentType() == segmentType).findFirst().get().getIsActive() == IsActiveOrInactive.a).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: What is `IsActiveOrInactive.a` and where it comes from? Can you provide a [*Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ? I.e. give us at least dummy classes and minimal amount of enclosing code so that it would be possible to execute this stream.

Comment: The info you are giving is not much to construct a lambda. I see that you are trying to assign the result so maybe you use removeIf. allowedToTradeProcessEquity.getList().stream().removeIf(x-> conditionLogic);